# Custom backref Text

Tags: biblatex, back-referencing

Hi I would like to change backref text. Here is what I mean:

[image]

Instead "Siehe S." I would like to have "Zitiert auf S.:"

Here is my MWE, and thanks for your help!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
     citecolor=black,
     filecolor=black,
     linkcolor=black,
     urlcolor=black
}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib} 
@incollection{athanasius1857,
    Address = {Parisiis},
    Author = {{Athanasius Alexandrinus}},
    Booktitle = {S. P. N. Athanasii archiepiscopi Alexandrini opera omnia quae exstant},
    Editor = {Jacques Paul Migne},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {14013-1422},
    Publisher = {Accurante J.-P. Migne},
    Series = {Patrologia Graeca},
    Shortauthor = {Ath.},
    Shorttitle = {ep. fest. 12.},
    Title = {Epistola XII heortastica},
    Volume = {26},
    Year = {1857}}
@book{athanasius1858,
    Address = {Parisiis},
    Author = {{Athanasius Alexandrinus}},
    Booktitle = {S. P. N. Athanasii archiepiscopi Alexandrini opera omnia quae exstant},
    Editor = {Jacques Paul Migne},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {1403-1412},
    Publisher = {Accurante J.-P. Migne},
    Series = {Patrologia Graeca},
    Shortauthor = {Ath.},
    Shorttitle = {ep. fest. 11.},
    Title = {Epistola XI heortastica},
    Volume = {26},
    Year = {1857}}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[style=historische-zeitschrift, maxnames=2, hyperref=true, backref=true, backrefstyle=none, backend=bibtex,idemtracker=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}
%
\begin{document}
\blindtext\footcite{athanasius1858}
\pagebreak
\blindtext\footcite{athanasius1857}
\pagebreak
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just a matter of adding

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
  backrefpage  = {Zitiert auf S\adddot},
  backrefpages = {Zitiert auf S\adddot},
}
```

to your preamble.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
     citecolor=black,
     filecolor=black,
     linkcolor=black,
     urlcolor=black
}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib} 
@incollection{athanasius1857,
    Address = {Parisiis},
    Author = {{Athanasius Alexandrinus}},
    Booktitle = {S. P. N. Athanasii archiepiscopi Alexandrini opera omnia quae exstant},
    Editor = {Jacques Paul Migne},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {14013-1422},
    Publisher = {Accurante J.-P. Migne},
    Series = {Patrologia Graeca},
    Shortauthor = {Ath.},
    Shorttitle = {ep. fest. 12.},
    Title = {Epistola XII heortastica},
    Volume = {26},
    Year = {1857}}
@book{athanasius1858,
    Address = {Parisiis},
    Author = {{Athanasius Alexandrinus}},
    Booktitle = {S. P. N. Athanasii archiepiscopi Alexandrini opera omnia quae exstant},
    Editor = {Jacques Paul Migne},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {1403-1412},
    Publisher = {Accurante J.-P. Migne},
    Series = {Patrologia Graeca},
    Shortauthor = {Ath.},
    Shorttitle = {ep. fest. 11.},
    Title = {Epistola XI heortastica},
    Volume = {26},
    Year = {1857}}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[
  style=historische-zeitschrift,
  maxnames=2,
  hyperref=true,
  backref=true,
  backrefstyle=none,
  backend=bibtex,
  idemtracker=true
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
  backrefpage  = {Zitiert auf S\adddot},
  backrefpages = {Zitiert auf S\adddot},
}

\begin{document}
\blindtext\footcite{athanasius1858}
\pagebreak
\blindtext\footcite{athanasius1857}
\pagebreak
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The OP wants to have a colon at the end, thus `\addcolon` can be added after `\adddot`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Just for curiosity, do German rules want/tolerate the colon in this case?

Comment: The OP wants it this way. I think, both is possible in German, but it is smoother without the colon. But the delimiter for the pages should be a simple comma, `historische-zeitschrift.bbx` redefines the `\*delim` commands to write a slash (because of the location entries).

Comment: Since I am not a native German I would also be interested if colon should come there :) But I guess thats not the question for this forum :P Thanks for your help!

Comment: @eklisiarh I would definitely prefer the version without the colon.